# How to ask a question about a person's order among her /his siblings?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, spoken-english

In most of the indian languages ,there is a WH question word used to ask about  a person's order among ones siblings . That is if she/he is the first , second or third child of ones parents. How to inquire about the same in English.Can we say?  How manieth child of your parents are you? or situation like as below

What is the order of Donald Trump among the presidents of USA?

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard, commonly-used way to ask this question in English. You have to use a bunch of words to explain what you are asking. Something like, "Where are you in the birth order among your parents' children? I mean, are you the first child, the second, or what?" Yes, it's awkward.

Comment: How to inquire about the order of the head of the nation among his predecessors ?  Secondly "What is your para ?" does any such usage exist in archaic English?

Comment: @AltafJahangir Same issue: There is no standard way to ask that. People trying to ask that in conversation often end up stumbling over their words. Like, "What number president was Bill Clinton? I mean, like, was he the 30th president or the 31st or what?"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by, "What is your para?" What's a "para"?

Answer (score 3):

English doesn't have a question word for that, and "how manieth" doesn't exist. You can ask "Are you the eldest child?" or "Are you the youngest of your siblings?" and you will probably get an answer beyond "yes" or "no". 
You might ask "Where do you fall among your brothers and sisters?"